# refresh needed instead of wrefresh?

Tags: ncurses

Why this piece of code here:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#define WIN 5
#define WI win[0]
#define WC win[1]

int ymax, xmax;
WINDOW *win[WIN];

int main(void)
{

    int i;
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    start_color();
    curs_set(0);
    noecho();
    init_pair(1,COLOR_GREEN,COLOR_BLACK);

    getmaxyx(stdscr, ymax, xmax);
    for(i=0; i<WIN; i++)
        win[i]= newwin(ymax, xmax, 0, 0);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);   /* We get F1, F2 etc..      */
    keypad(win[0], TRUE);   /* We get F1, F2 etc..      */

    refresh();

    wprintw(WI, "Screen 1\n");
    wprintw(WC, "Screen 2\n");

    wattrset(WI, COLOR_PAIR(1));
    wrefresh(WI);

    getch();
    endwin();
    printf("\nThanks for playing\n");
    return 0;
}
```

does not work if I delete the

```
refresh();
```

line?

Also, please, I'm new to this ncurses stuff, so if you see any other misconcept, be kind to point, specially the procedure to exit without leaving loose ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that one cannot mix `getch()` with other windows. `getch()` do a `refresh()`. One should use `wgetch(WI)` instead.

Still puzzles me why using the `refresh()` in the begin of the code made the text appear. But I think that to understand this behavior I would need to post the entire code to see how the functions mix all the screens.

Now with `wgetch()` the problem is gone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877876/how-to-use-ncurses-h-function-waddstr-properly
I have the same problem, but I cant understand 2 moments: Why my code working in cycle when I'm using waddstr() and wrefresh().  Why it's work fine with mvaddstr() and wrefresh()? So, the problem appears only in the case of using waddstr() and wrefresh() not in cycle. Please help